# How to make multiple counter using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to make mini poll using multiple counter. 
You can see I made it single button by single counter. Is it possible to make it multiple counter by one or two function? And then I like to make it using JavaScript.
Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
 var counter1 = document.getElementById("btn1-counter");

 counter1.innerHTML = 0;
 btn1.onclick = function()
 {
    counter1.innerHTML++;
 };

 var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
 var counter2 = document.getElementById("btn2-counter");

 counter2.innerHTML = 0;
 btn2.onclick = function()
 {
    counter2.innerHTML++;
 };
</script>
```

Comment: It may be helpful to see the HTML markup you are affecting with this JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a generic javascript function which utilizes the "event" param to selected the appropriate counter to increase.

```
var inc_counter = function(event){
    let id = event.target.id;
    var counter = document.getElementById(id + "-counter");
    counter.innerHTML++;
}
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var counter1 = document.getElementById("btn1-counter");
btn1.onclick=inc_counter;
counter1.innerHTML = 0;

var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var counter2 = document.getElementById("btn2-counter");
btn2.onclick = inc_counter;
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Yay, It is! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding, but why not just write the following: 
unless you need the counters to increment at different times. At that point you may have to keep your event listeners separate.

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
var counter1 = document.getElementById("btn1-counter");
var counter2 = document.getElementById("btn2-counter");
counter1.innerHTML=0;
counter2.innerHTML=0;

function count(){
counter1.innerHTML++;
counter2.innerHTML++;
}
btn.addEventListener(count,false);
```